# Laravel empty request after send ajax on keyup

Tags: ajax, laravel, request, laravel-8

I have empty request from ajax.
In site request send this input value but controller not catching any request value
my code:

```
public function searchUser(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $string = $request->input('searchUser');

    $user = DB::table('users')->where('name', 'LIKE','%'. $string.'%')
        ->orWhere('surname', 'LIKE','%'. $string.'%')
        ->orWhere('phone_number', 'LIKE','%'. $string.'%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE','%'. $string.'%')


        ->get();


    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user,
        'string' => $string,
        'request'=>$request
    ]);
}
```

https://pastebin.com/YqWkL7xP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have view your JavaScript in Pastebin

```
$.ajax({
.
.
.
  data: {
     'searchUser': textFieldValue
  },
.
.
.
});
```

I think the variable name in the data you want to pass into controller should same with controller

**Controller.php**

```
$string = $request->input('searchUser');
.
.
.
```

You also can change the variable name ***searchUser*** be ***string*** too in the controller, It must be same.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did not notice this misspelling